# Redirect to a channel as well as ping a role then post a message using args

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm making an announcement command for my bot and want it to go to the announcements channel automatically, then ping the first role mentioned and finally display the message.

For now I have it going to staff commands as a placeholder to get it working, this does not work or throw an error. It properly pings the role, but nothing after that shows up, even the "Debug". What am I missing. I've seen the channel part work but it doesn't for me, and I can't find a similar situation online for the message itself.

```
module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    let prefix = config.prefix;
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

    const channel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === '｜staff-cmds');

    let pingRole = message.mentions.roles.first(); 
    let messageContent = args.slice(1).join(' ');

      channel.send(pingRole, messageContent, "Debug");
```

[This is what happens when the command is run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZwt7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `` channel.send(`${pingRole} ${messageContent}`) ``
The `channel.send()` function takes only two parameter "content" and "options" you can read more about it [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/DMChannel?scrollTo=send)

Comment: Thank you, totally skipped over that in the docs.